# angular cli installation cannot be completed

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install, npm-package

I am using windows 10, and Nodejs v20.11.1. installed.
when I trying to install angular cli, installation progress completed and show me this message: "changed 232 packages in 4s".
but angular cli is not actually installed! and there is not any files in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules" path!

I am tried these solutions but still not worked:

- deactivate windows antivirus.
- clean the npm cache.
- delete npm AppData and nodejs Folers manually and reinstall nodejs.

Comment: What does the command `node -v` shows?

Comment: shows this: v20.11.1

Comment: Do you get any results when running `ng --help`? If yes, CLI is installed globally, as it is supposed to.

Comment: no i couldn't run any ng command :(

Comment: please try running: `npx ng --help`. sometimes - depending on the shell you are using - the node_modules/.bin folder is not in the path.

Comment: Thank you, I'm at working now, but try it later.